# Is there an MVC5 model attribute for setting HTML Size attribute and MaxLength?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In the past I have used a custom class (HtmlProperties) in MVC3 to set HTML properties within razor by declaring my model object like below.

```
[HtmlProperties(Size = 1, MaxLength = 2)]
public string MyModelField{ get; set; }
```

Is there an MVC5 equivalent to do something like this without having to build a custom class?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, although you could vote for it on [codeplex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1237)...

Comment: Can you add Html properties inside Razor View or would you like necessarily to define them in ViewModel?

Comment: I would prefer to define them in the model or viewmodel to avoid having to instruct razor each time it implements the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as far as I know, ViewModel and Model are **not** supposed to contain information about how things are going to be rendered. They are supposed to contain only types (eg. field is string) and requirements (eg. field not empty).

Therefore IMHO rendering objects (how inputs should look like) should be inside of Razor View. In fact MVC5 has added new option to achieve that - you can pass `htmlAttributes` object to `additionalViewData` object argument while rendering EditorFor.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", custom_attribute = "lol" } })
```

This was not possible in MVC3 and MVC4, since few Html Helpers accepted `htmlAttributes` as an argument and few Html Helpes accepted only `additionalViewData`

Also I think you should rather use `[MaxLength(int i)]` if you intend to limit length of the input in ViewModel (as this will also help MVC to validate it client and server side)

```
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 for emphasizing that this information does not belong in the ViewModel or the Model. It is presentation information that belongs expressly in the View.